# add row of non-matching column types to existing dataframe

Tags: r, bind, rows, tidyverse

I want to add a row to an existing data frame (or tibble) of mixed column types that contains only characters for each 'column'. This is how I got it to work, which should be good enough but it seems that this should be easier.

df is representative of a more complicated data frame that I have previously created.

```
df <- read_csv("12, 34, 10\n10, 29, 14",
          col_names = c("part_1", 
                        "part_2", 
                        "part_3"))

c_name <- colnames(df)

info <- read_csv("blue, green, small\n0,0,0",
                 col_names = c_name) %>%
        filter(part_1 > 0)

results <- data.table::rbindlist(list(info, df))
```

Which does generate the correct output:

```
part_1  part_2  part_3
  blue   green   small
    12      34      10
    10      29      14
```

But like I said, it seems to me that there should be an easier way to do this staying within the tidyverse. When I tried this by using bind_rows I got the error :

> "Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
>         Can not automatically convert from character to integer in  column "part_1".

Any suggestions?

Comment: `bind_rows` and `bind_cols` don't implicitly convert your column types. You are trying to bind character columns with integer ones. Use `mutate_all` to convert integers to character before using either: `bind_rows(list(info, mutate_all(df, as.character)))`.

Comment: If you're doing this for some report or something, a better way might be to make column names with line breaks in them: `names(df) = paste(names(df), c("blue", "green", "small"), sep = "\n")`. This will preserve your column classes and *might* print correctly (depending on your output format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert all columns to characters using `mutate_all` on both dataframes inside `map`:

```
results <- purrr::map(list(info, df), function(x){
  x %>%
    mutate_all(as.character)
}) %>%
  do.call(rbind, .)
```

If you really want to use `bind_rows` you could do this:

```
results <- info %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%
              mutate_all(as.character))
```

This is assuming you want to make sure all columns in both `info` and `df` are characters, if you know for sure that `info` will be characters then you can drop the first `mutate_all`

Comment: Thanks everyone, all response do get the desired results, I like this last option with bind_rows by tbradley the best. And I learned something new, I did not know one could pipe within function call like that,cool.                                                                                               You are correct @crazybilly, this is just for presentation so additional calcs at this stage is in-necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, I'd like to persuade you not to do this: by definition, in R, data frame columns are all of one type, mixing types within a column (in this case, character strings mixed with numeric values), forces R to fall back to the lowest type, see the section about [Vectors May Only Have One Type on this page](http://nicercode.github.io/2014-02-18-UTS/lessons/01-intro_r/data-structures.html).

The problem is that you end up with a bunch of things that look like numbers, but are actually just text--if you need to do any more arithmetic or analysis on them, you're hosed.

That said, occasionally, I have call to do something similar, when I'm formatting a table for presentation. In that case, you'll need to coerce the values in df to character first:

```
df %>%
   purrr::map_df(as.character) %>% # loop through each column and apply as.charater()
   bind_rows(info)
```

Comment: To drop the `purrr` dependency you could do `df %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% ...`